# Excel date/time frequency keeps returning 0

Tags: excel, count, excel-formula, frequency

I have a column of date/time entries in the format of `Sun Nov 23 23:59:48 GMT 2014`.

I applied the frequency formula `=FREQUENCY(A2:A9,H2:H4)` to get the number of intervals of all the times. However, it keeps returning zeros. I suspect it's something to do with letters occurring with the numbers.

Comment: What is in columns A and H?

Comment: A is the timestamps and H is intervals of a minute

Comment: Are those values in A "real" Excel times?  In other words, if you enter a formula such as =ISTEXT(A1), with the timestamp in A1, it should return FALSE.  If not, you will need to convert your times to "real" excel times, and also ensure that "H" contains "real" minute data.  Also, if you, in another cell, enter =A! and format it as General, it should show a value of 41966.99986.

Comment: The data is coming from a java program where it is converted to a string in order to be passed to an excel file. I checked both columns and they returned true.

Answer (score 0):

From what you write in the comments, it seems your values are text strings and not "real" excel date/times.  You will need to either change the java program to output proper dates for Excel (Excel dates are values representing days and fractions of a day since 1 Jan 1900), or change the strings in Excel to "real" date/times.

For the date/time stamps, the following should work, although there could be issues depending on the international settings of your computer:

```
= DATEVALUE(MID(A1,5,6) & ", " & RIGHT(A1,4))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

(You can then custom format the result to show the same format as your text string from java).

For the minutes, you can convert them to the proper values with a formula like:

```
=TIME(0,H1,0)
```

However, your FREQUENCY function may not work as you expect, since there will be NO date/times that occur, for example, between minute one and minute two.

Depending on what you really want to do, you might consider a Pivot Table, grouping the times appropriately (e.g. by minutes)

**EDIT** In response to pnuts comment below, here is a formula that should work regardless of the international formatting, so long as the time separator is the colon:

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),MATCH(MID(A1,5,3),{"Jan";"Feb";"Mar";"Apr";"May";"Jun";"Jul";"Aug";"Sep";"Oct";"Nov";"Dec"},0),MID(A1,9,2))+TIMEVALUE(MID(A1,12,8))
```

Comment: @pnuts Thanks for that.  I did write that there might be issues with certain regional settings or international versions, but I did not test them.  Your comment provoked me to present a version that should work with most settings, though.